# Array of object is getting undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-context

This is my `Cart.jsx`

```
import { createContext, useEffect } from "react"
import Cake from "../About Section/Cake";
const PdtList = createContext();
export default function Cart() {
    let list = [
        {
            id: "52",
            name: "Doll cake"
            // images: image80
        },
        {
            id: "53",
            name: "Mixed Platte cake"
            // images: image81
        },
        {
            id: "54",
            name: "Pinata cake"
            // images: image82
        },
        {
            id: "55",
            name: "Bomb cake"
            // images: image83
        }
    ];
    return (
        <>
            <main className="align" >
                <h1>Thanks for shopping with us</h1>
                <PdtList.Provider value={list}>
                    <Cake />
                </PdtList.Provider>

            </main>
        </>
    )
}
export { PdtList };
```

This is the `Cake.jsx`

```
import { PdtList } from "../Cart/Cart";
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function Cake(props) {
  const { name, images, bold, cut } = props;
  const list = useContext(PdtList);
  console.log(list);
  console.log(typeof(list));
  const Add_Products = (index) => {
    console.log('Add_Products called');
    let tobeAdded = { name, images, bold };
  };
  return (
    <>
      <main className="align unique">
        <img src={images} alt="" />
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <div className="align2">
          <small>Rs {bold}</small>
          <small style={{ margin: "0px 10px" }}></small>
          <small
            style={{ "fontSize": "15px", textDecoration: "line-through" }}
          >
            Rs {cut}
          </small>
        </div>
        <button onClick={Add_Products} style={{ margin: "10px 0px" }}>
          Click here
        </button>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

This is the  console,

[image]

When I am trying to console the list in the `Add_Products` function in the Cake.jsx then I am getting undefined.

This is a working codesandbox [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-currying-rzo6zd?file=/src/Cart.jsx)

This is the Birthday.jsx

```
import image60 from './assets/cake60.jpeg'
import image61 from './assets/cake61.jpeg'
import image62 from './assets/cake62.jpeg'
import image63 from './assets/cake63.jpeg'
import image64 from './assets/cake64.jpeg'
import image65 from './assets/cake65.jpeg'
import image66 from './assets/cake66.jpeg'
import image67 from './assets/cake67.jpeg'
import image68 from './assets/cake68.jpeg'
import image69 from './assets/cake69.jpeg'
import Cake from './Cake'
import { useContext } from "react"
import { PdtList } from "../Cart/Cart"
const pdtArray = [{
    id: '32',
    name: "Anniversary cake",
    images: image60
},
{
    id: '33',
    name: "Anniversary cake",
    images: image61
},
{
    id: '134',
    name: "Anniversary cake",
    images: image62
},
{
    id: '34',
    name: "Anniversary cake",
    images: image63
},
{
    id: '35',
    name: "Anniversary cake",
    images: image64
},
{
    id: '36',
    name: "Anniversary cake",
    images: image65
},
{
    id: '37',
    name: "Anniversary cake",
    images: image66
},
{
    id: '38',
    name: "Anniversary cake",
    images: image67
},
{
    id: '39',
    name: "Anniversary cake",
    images: image68
},
{
    id: '40',
    name: "Anniversary cake",
    images: image69
},]
export default function Birthday(props) {
    const list = useContext(PdtList);
    console.log(list);
    const { title } = props;
    return (
        <>
            <main className='PDT_heading align' >
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <div className="grid_system">
                    {
                        pdtArray.map((e) => {
                            const { name, images, id } = e;
                            return (
                                <Cake key={id} name={name} images={images} cut="232" bold="343" />
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </main>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: In your Birthday/Anniversary component you have a load of Cake components but you don't have a context provider above them in the tree

Comment: I have added the Birthday.jsx Can you suggest me some edits? And yes the error is due to that only thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are going to use the `useContext` in a component, make sure that component is wrapped inside the `Context.Provider` (either the component or the parent of the component). Only then the `useContext` can able to access the values of the context else it will return the default value which is `undefined`.

So, the root component will be something lie:

```js
<StrictMode>
    <PdtList.Provider value={list}>
      <Cart />
      <Birthday />
    </PdtList.Provider>
  </StrictMode>
```

I wrapped the components inside the Provider so all the components inside can able to access the value.

working link: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-driscoll-j2jb7r?file=/src/Birthday.jsx)